# How can we integrate Twitter login with a java based website developed using the play framework?

Tags: java, playframework, frameworks

```
 public static void getTokens()
    {
        Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer("", "");
        try {
            RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
        }
        catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Is this correct method of passing tokens? We need to render twitter sign up page when user clicks login button